# "Save as webpage, complete" problem?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, html, css

I have a problem when I am trying to save web page from browser using "Save as Webpage, complete" some of CSS/Javascript/Image are not saved, thus when I reopen saved page offline webpage can't display properly. How do I solve this?

How do I made webpage can be saved properly from browser ? I don't want to use MHT ext. Because what my situation here is I need to give URL for web designer to launch URL, saved webpage and modify CSS/HTML.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It seems to me that as long as you have the info, it doesn't matter what it looks like. You could always take a screen shot to preserve the layout.

Answer (score 3):

From your question i understand the ultimate goal is to send all of your assets for your web page to your designer so they can edit the css, graphics etc.

Could you not just zip up all the assets and email it across to the web designer? If this is your web page then you should already have the assets no?

If you try and use save web page complete, it normally messes with the html code anyway so this would not be useful for your designer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue; if ajax is used in the page, you can't see the saved page properly. (For example, at first div's are hidden (display:none;) after page is loaded all the hidden divs get revealed.)

We need Final HTML code (Javascript functions executed and all data appearing on screen loaded from server)

I used Firebug's HTML tab to grab that Final HTML Code.

Copy the entire "html" branch and doctype declaration paste into a file. Then copy styles and images folders to the same folder.

[image]

Comment: In Firefox built-in Inspector nowadays, after right clicking an element, similar list of choices is a layer down, under Copy.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) a shot - while its meant for offline browsing, it probably does what you want - i used to to back up a wiki (of my own) into offline, static pages for reference. Just make sure you select the options correctly - it can do spidering and you obviously want a single page ;)

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to change all links to the full link of the web site, then when you will "Save as Webpage, complete" all the thinks that will not be saved will be used online.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other browsers like Chrome or Opera? IIRC Opera's "Save As" function is quite good.

Like hairbymaurice said, if it's your own web page then you must have the files your designer can edit.

If it's not your web page then why would you want to edit it? Sounds like you're trying to steal/copy the site to me.

Comment: Unfortunately Chrome and recent versions of Opera have the same problem. Apparently old versions of Opera (before version 9 I believe? Or 7?) could do this, but it seems to have been dropped.

Answer (score 0):

In FF25.0.1, this worked:

- open `about:config` in the NavBar
- accept warning
- search for "save" & find `browser.download.save_converter_index`.  This was originally set to 1, but on resetting (right click & choose Reset) it changed to 0 which immediately resolved the problem.

Comment: Nope, this is simply how the "Save page as > format" option is stored behind the scenes. 0 = web page only, 1 = web page complete, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try a shot with SaveWeb2ZIP*. It downloads all fonts, images, scripts, HTML and styles in one ZIP file that you can unpack. Looks 100% the same, just like the original one!!

*Android 6, Allview A5 Ready, Opera 71.3.3718.67322

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).